# How to change url in PHP?

Tags: php, browser

Is there any methods other than **header** and **link** to change the browser url in php ?

Comment: Are those, for some reason, insufficient?

Comment: Why don't these two satisfy your need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`header` issues a header to the browser. It can be used to redirect (when using the "Location:" header, which sends a 302 redirect) but is also used to serve any arbitrary header (for setting MIME types, for example).

`link` is used to create hardlinks on a filesystem and has nothing to do with browser URLs.

If you wish to mask a URL as another and are running PHP with Apache, consider using an `.htaccess` file and `mod_rewrite` to set up URL rewriting rules. For more info, consult the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).